# Overriding renderer to browser type in jupyter notebook for plotly

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I'm new to plotly so trying to run different renderers instead of jupyter notebook's default renderer. 
I'm using 'browser' as renderer. But it is not showing the plot, it just creates a new tab and it just display 'Can't reach the page' message and does not display the plot.

Below is the code that I'm using:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Bar(y=[2,3,1]))
fig.show(renderer='browser')
```

Comment: this is working now, restarted my kernal and executed the above code again. It worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Restart the kernal in jupyter notebook and execute the code again.